# Notepad++ Find in HTML string

Tags: notepad++

I have an html document I'm editing in Notepadd++. It has around a thousand links like below in a document that is 60,000 lines long:

```
    <a href="https://www.example.com/quizzes/view/#" class="btn discussion-button-print-none">
                                            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                                            &nbsp; Discussion &nbsp;
                                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">4</span>
                                        </a>
```

I want the entire link <a href... - '/a> gone. The problem I keep running into is the number in between the span tags is different. *Above it is 4*. I want to find them all and replace them with blank spaces. I was trying to play around with some other Regex options I read about while looking for an answer but none worked for me.

Comment: So you want to remove `<a href="https://www.example.com/quizzes/view/#" class="btn discussion-button-print-none">`  and `</a>` also you want to replace all span values?

Comment: I want to delete all 1000  "<a href="https://www.example.com....   </a>" I want the entire code block above gone. I had started doing it manually but that's gonna take forever. I was just highlighting the 5 lines and pressing Delete.

Answer (score 0):

I found I was easily able to do this with my Sublime text editor with a wildcard(.*) Notepad++ was NOT the way to go.:

```
<a href="https://www.examtopics.com/exams/comptia/sy0-501/view/#" class="btn btn-secondary question-discussion-button d-print-none">
                                            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                                            &nbsp; Discussion &nbsp;
                                                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">.*</span>
                                        </a>
```

Comment: It works exactly the same way in Notepad++ but be carefull with `.*`, it's greedy, you need to use `.*?`.